# Excel: Calculating differences between 2 values in a large range of cells

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would be very happy to get some advice on how to, in a range of cells, calculate differences between 2 values:

1. 20:25:37,000
2. 20:25:36,670
3. 20:25:36,669
4. 20:25:36,610
5. 20:25:36,492
6. 20:25:36,410
7. 20:25:36,409
8. 20:25:36,289

I would like to use a pattern here. First I want to calculate 1-4 and then 5-8, etc...
Is there any efficient way to perform this by some formula that you can use with autofill for instance?

Much grateful for tips

Comment: What's the meaning of calculate? How do you calculate the values?

Comment: I would like to make subtraction for the given values, i.e. 1 minus 4, 5 minus 8, etc where these numbers are pointing to the list above.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry It was a typo, I corrected it now. And yes you are right, I think I made it more complicated in my mind than it needed to be.

Comment: Given your posted data and question, you'd best post some examples of results from that data.  Do you want to ignore 2,3,6,7?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes I wanted to ignore those numbers. I just came with the solution and I just needed to autofill and then forget about the remaining cells that I dont need.

Comment: Do you have Office 365?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes using the Desktop version, version 2102 (version 13801.20960).

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365, you can use the formula below to create your sequence of operations:

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(ROWS(myRange)/4,,1,4),
y,SEQUENCE(ROWS(myRange)/4,,4,4),
INDEX(myRange,x)-INDEX(myRange,y))
```

- The "magic" is in the `SEQUENCE` function which creates an array consisting of the relevant rows to consider for each factor.
- We then use that argument in the `INDEX` function to return the relevant values.

The results will `SPILL` down from the formula.